# Neo4j Cypher building a graph using csv

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

Good afternoon!
I have a csv file with the following structure:

```
numberRow,A,B,C
0,a1,b1,c1
1,,,c2
2,,b2,c3
3,a2,b3,c4
4,,,c5
...
```

I upload it using, for other nodes, the script is similar

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///file.csv' AS row
WITH row
  WHERE row.a IS NOT NULL
CREATE
  (aa:A {numberRow: toInteger(row.numberRow), value: row.a});
```

My task is to get a graph of the following form

```
CREATE
  (a1:A {numberRow: 0, value: 'a1'})-[:R]-(b1:B {numberRow: 0, value: 'b1'})-[:R]->(c1:C {numberRow: 0, value: 'c1'}),
  (a1)-[:R]-(b1)-[:R]->(c2:C {numberRow: 1, value: 'c2'}),
  (a1)-[:R]-(b2:B {numberRow: 2, value: 'b2'})-[:R]->(c3:C {numberRow: 2, value: 'c3'}),
  (a2:A {numberRow: 3, value: 'a2'})-[:R]-(b3:B {numberRow: 3, value: 'b3'})-[:R]->(c4:C {numberRow: 3, value: 'c4'}),
  (a2)-[:R]-(b3)-[:R]->(c5:C {numberRow: 4, value: 'c5'})
```

Please tell me how to make a request for drawing up a graph, possibly with loading all nodes with it together, I am grateful in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case requires keeping track of the items in the previous rows. I would suggest to first create a complete array, and merge from there. Creating a complete array could be done using `REDUCE` and loop through the items:

```
WITH [ 
       {numberRow:0,A:'a1',B:'b1',C:'c1'},
       {numberRow:1,C:'c2'},
       {numberRow:2,B:'b2',C:'c3'},
       {numberRow:3,A:'a2',B:'b3',C:'c4'},       
       {numberRow:4,C:'c5'}      
     ] AS rows
UNWIND rows AS row

WITH row ORDER BY row.numberRow ASC
WITH COLLECT(row) AS rows

RETURN REDUCE(arr=[], row IN rows |
            arr
            + {
                numberRow: row.numberRow,
                A:COALESCE(row.A,LAST(arr).A),
                B:COALESCE(row.B,LAST(arr).B),
                C:COALESCE(row.C,LAST(arr).C)
              }
           ) AS completeArray
```